# How to convert `Stream<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>` to a List?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch all users except the current user from the Firestore collections, but I've got this error:

```
The argument type 'QueryDocumentSnapshot<Object?>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<String, dynamic>').
```

A fragment of my code:

```
Future <List<kako.User>> fetchAllUsers(User currentUser) async {
    List<kako.User> userList =  List<kako.User>.generate(20, (index)=>kako.User());
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await fireStore.collection("users").get();
    for (var i = 0; i < querySnapshot.docs.length ; i++) {
        if(querySnapshot.docs[i].id != currentUser.uid){
            userList.add(kako.User.fromMap(querySnapshot.docs[i].data()));
        }
    }
    return userList;
}
```

`querySnapshot.docs[i].data()` is underlined with red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
userList.add(kako.User.fromMap(querySnapshot.docs[i].data() as Map<String, dynamic>))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your `userList` simply like this

```
List<kako.User> userList = [];
```

Get the QuerySnapshot

```
QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await fireStore.collection("users").get();
```

Map each of QuerySnapshot docs into your `kako.User` model, and lastly cast it into list by `toList()`

```
userList = querySnapshot.docs.map((e) => kako.User.fromMap(e.data())).toList();
```

Therefore, your `userList` is already contain documents of the `users` we fetched